# To find any service pack installed in my Farm. SharePoint 2013?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, service-pack

I want to find is there any service pack installed in my sharepoint. I am using SharePoint 2013.  can anyone help me how to find any service pack installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this: http://www.toddklindt.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=346

You have SharePoint 2013 SP1 (the good SP). You can also go to the System Settings -> Manage Servers in this farm to get the farm build.